# Cannot validate in MVC 5 authentication with both UserName and Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Validation works fine but if I change Account/Register

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

to

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
```

Validation always fails Account/Login

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Is this a known bug or am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your call to SignInManger.PasswordSignInAsync you are still sending in the email as the username that you would like to use to authenticate instead of the UserName property.

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: I want it to be authenticated using email, just adding username for better text

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are getting when making that call?

Comment: Its not error the result = "Failure" so goes on default case